# Error using Mutate_all in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have to check if I have negative values in all the columns from my dataframe.

Here is the structure of my DF from the list of Dataframes, all of them have the same structure.

```
     FECHA   SPX Index MCUDNA Index  SX5E Index MXEMSC Index MXME Index 
2 2010-12-31 332.636     332.63        242.86     237.44      567.35
3 2011-01-07 334.327     334.327       808.25     234.02      235.26
4 2011-01-14 341.771     341.771       2920.40    244.95      247.43
```

Ok, I have to check if all of my columns from each dataframe has the same dim as the FECHA column, for example if FECHA column has 273 rows, SPX INDEX should have the same, but I have to check if all the values are positives.

I explain it, vela parameter is a list of dataframes, all of them have the same structure as the last dataframe.

Here is my code:

```
valorNegativos = function (vela) {
  dim_pxlast = dim(vela[[1]])[1]
  for(a in 1:length(vela)) {
    mutate_all(vela[[a]], funs( ifelse (length(vela[[a]]$. >= 0) == dim_pxlast) , print(paste0("Datos correctos" )), stop("ERROR: Existen datos negativos")))
  }
}
```

In the first line I obtain my correct dimension, and with mutate_all I walk throught all my columns checking if all the values are positives, then I count all the positives values and with the ifelse I check if they have the same dimension, if not , I run Stop error, and I stop the execution of my program.

I don't know why this error is happening.

**Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: argument "yes" is missing, with no default.**

Answer (score 0):

Solved... it was an error because I didnt' close the ifelse statement...

```
valorNegativos = function (vela) {
  dim_pxlast = dim(vela[[1]])[1]
  for(a in 1:length(vela)) {
    #mutate_all(vela[[a]], funs( ifelse( sum((vela[[a]]$. > 0) == TRUE) / ncol(vela[a]) == length(vela[[a]]$FECHA), print(paste0("Datos correctos" )), stop("ERROR: Existen datos negativos"))))
    mutate_all(vela[[a]], funs( ifelse (length(vela[[a]]$. >= 0) == dim_pxlast , TRUE , stop("ERROR: Existen datos negativos"))))
  }
}
```